# Display offline html in android app with a tablet

Tags: android, html, browser

I have to create an android app, that displays an offline html website. Does android sdk have an internal browser control? What kind of dev sw do you recommend to create this basic wrapper?

Answer (score 0):

**Read about [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html).**

It's built-in webrowser engine and you can use it to your target.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. WebView

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

This component allows you to specific a local url (file://) if required or even passed the complete html to the `load` method. Also capable of event handling for more advanced scenarios.

Comment: Why did you double my answer ?

Comment: It's a good answer, worth saying twice. :) No, it it just wasn't there when I clicked the answer button. It does happen sometimes.

Comment: So why did you write "Yes" ?